# Move database with bcrypt password field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, bcrypt

I have a postgres database running at heroku. In the database I store passwords using bcrypt. The app is a Ruby on Rails 3 app using custom authorization. The authorization is using the rails method has_secure_password for the passwords.

I have planned to move my app to a VPS instead.

Will all my users passwords still be working after moving the database? I'm asking this because I'm not sure how the passwords are salted. Is the method used to crypt the passwords not tied to the database server in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source - [bcrypt-ruby](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/)

> "Hash algorithms take a chunk of data (e.g., your user‘s password) and
>   create a "digital fingerprint," or hash, of it. Because this process
>   is not reversible, there‘s no way to go from the hash back to the
>   password."

Assuming your storing a password hash and salt as a string then you will be able to store this in any data store. Take a look in db/schema and you will probably find that you are doing this.